# Open port 5900 via the command line?

Tags: iptables, vnc

I am running Fedora 18 with KDE.  I opened port 5900 via the GUI yesterday and was using VNC just fine, but then tried to open the port for SMTP via a couple of different methods and now the VNC connection is "closing unexpectedly."

That's a vague error but I'm thinking it is a firewall issue.  The problem is that I don't have any graphical way to access the firewall now, just via ssh.  I tried adding an IPTABLES line, `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5900 -j ACCEPT`, but that didn't seem to make a difference and when I tried `iptables --List` there was nothing that appeared to be about port 5900. Did I do the iptables line wrong?  Should it be OUTPUT instead of INPUT? `-I` instead of `-A`?  udp instead of tcp?

I would also like to know why "`iptables --List`" did not seem to have anything about port 5900 in it.  Is it possible that Fedora 18 no longer uses iptables?

Anyone have suggestions?  It's been hours since I've had no GUI access and I'm getting desperate...  :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
/sbin/service iptables restart
```

was the missing ingredient to this puzzle.  For some reason /sbin/service firewall restart did not work...

Answer (score 0):

Did you save the iptable before you restarted it with

```
/sbin/service iptables save
```

Comment: This won't work, will it? iptables isn't a service, it's a command. To save, you run `iptables-save > iptables-save.out`.